# ¿Cómo puedo obtener los cuatro últimos productos de una base de datos filtrando por fecha?

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos

Estoy intentando obtener los cuatro últimos productos subidos a la base de datos.

En los productos tengo los atributos `codigo, nombre, descripcion, precio, fecha de publicacion, fecha de venta`.

Mi idea principal es filtrar por la `fecha de publicación` de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT MAX(fecha_publi) 
   FROM  Productos;
```

El inconveniente es que esto solo me devuelve una tupla y necesito cuatro.

Answer (score 0):

La forma de hacerlo depende del motor de base de datos que utilices. Si es compatible con Transact SQL, entonces la consulta utilizando SELECT LIMIT te dará los resultados que necesitas. Si el motor es basado en SQL Server o MASAccess, entonces deberás utilizar SELECT TOP.

Utilizando LIMIT debes utilizar esta sintaxys:

> SELECT expressions 
>  FROM tables
>  [WHERE conditions]
>  [ORDER
> BY expression [ ASC | DESC ]]
>  LIMIT number_rows [ OFFSET
> offset_value ];

Tu consulta quedaría entonces:

```
SELECT * FROM productos ORDER BY fecha DESC LIMIT 4
```

`LIMIT` especifica el número máximo de filas a retornar.

En el caso de MSAccess or SQL Server te quedará:

```
SELECT TOP(4) * FROM productos ORDER BY fecha DESC
```

`TOP( n )` especifica el número máximo de filas a retornar.